# Insert values of dict1 into dict2 but in a specific place in dict2

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have 2 dictionaries and I want to insert the values of dict1 into dict2 but in a specific place in dict2, ie:

dict1

```
{
'apple': 'hard tasty', 'orange': 'soft tasty', 'banana': 'soft very-tasty'
}
```

dict2

```
{
 'apple': '<div class="apple"></div>',
 'orange': '<div class="orange"></div>',
 'banana': '<div class="banana"></div>'
 }
```

I want to insert the values of dict1 into dict2 inside the 'class=' variable so it becomes

Desired

```
{
 'apple': '<div class="apple hard tasty"></div>',
 'orange': '<div class="orange soft tasty"></div>',
 'banana': '<div class="banana soft very-tasty"></div>'
 }
```

Can you help me with this? I may have to import re or use regex. I've been using dict comprehensions for the iterations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of `regex` or any additional imports. Use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead:

```
dict1 = {
       'apple': 'hard tasty', 'orange': 'soft tasty',   
       'banana': 'soft very-tasty'
        }
dict2 = {
       'apple': '<div class="apple"></div>',
       'orange': '<div class="orange"></div>',
       'banana': '<div class="banana"></div>'
        }

d = {k: v.replace(k, k+' '+dict1[k]) for k, v in dict2.items()}
print(d)

# {'apple': '<div class="apple hard tasty"></div>', 
#  'orange': '<div class="orange soft tasty"></div>', 
#  'banana': '<div class="banana soft very-tasty"></div>'}
```

Comment: How would we solve it if dict2's values were: 
`'apple': '<div class="a"></div>', 'orange': '<div class="o"></div>', 'banana': '<div class="b"></div>'`
and we wanted it to be:
`'apple': '<div class="a hard tasty"></div>', 'orange': '<div class="o soft tasty"></div>', 'banana': '<div class="b soft very-tasty"></div>'`
with dict1 still being:
`'apple': 'hard tasty', 'orange': 'soft tasty','banana': 'soft very-tasty`

Comment: Can you ask this as a new question, because the original question is already answered and I don't want to make changes to that and confuse future readers. I will answer there.

Comment: Ok i've opened a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911943/update-value-of-dict2-from-dict1-but-in-a-specific-place-in-dict2