# Update value of dict2 from dict1 but in a specific place in dict2

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

Having 2 dictionaries I want to insert the values of dict1 into dict2 but in a specific place in dict2

[I asked a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906279/insert-values-of-dict1-into-dict2-but-in-a-specific-place-in-dict2) which was solved in this way:

```
d = {k: v.replace(k, k+' '+dict1[k]) for k, v in dict2.items()}
```

But I'm interested in how we would solve this similar problem:

Dict1

```
{
'apple': 'hard tasty', 'orange': 'soft tasty', 'banana': 'soft very-tasty'
}
```

Dict2

```
{
 'apple': '<div class="a"></div>',
 'orange': '<div class="o"></div>',
 'banana': '<div class="b a"></div>'
 }
```

Insert the values of dict1 into dict2 inside the "class=" variable so it becomes:

```
{
 'apple': '<div class="a hard tasty"></div>',
 'orange': '<div class="o soft tasty"></div>',
 'banana': '<div class="b a soft very-tasty"></div>'
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
d = {'apple': 'hard tasty', 'orange': 'soft tasty', 'banana': 'soft very-tasty'}
d1 = {'apple': '<div class="a"></div>', 'orange': '<div class="o"></div>', 'banana': '<div class="b a"></div>'}
new_d = {a:re.sub('(?<=class\=")[\w+\s\-\_]+(?=")', lambda x:x.group()+' '+d[a], b) for a, b in d1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'apple': '<div class="a hard tasty"></div>', 'orange': '<div class="o soft tasty"></div>', 'banana': '<div class="b a soft very-tasty"></div>'}
```

Comment: @Ajax1234, "banana" doesn't return the exact result in OP's question. Not that it matters in this case since class order shouldn't matter but may be something to look into.

Comment: So i've tested this one and it seems to split values separated by the "-" character, ie if for d1, if `<div class="b a"></div>` is `<div class="b-test a"></div>`, the output is `<div class="b soft very-tasty-testing a"></div>`

Comment: @PaulGwamanda I updated the regex in my answer. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Fantastic, I've made this work in all my datasets, i need to do some reading on regex was always afraid of it :p

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as the answer to your first question, here is my solution using `re.sub`:

```
import re

dict1 = {'apple': 'hard tasty', 'orange': 'soft tasty', 'banana': 'soft very-tasty'}

dict2 = {'apple': '<div class="a"></div>',
         'orange': '<div class="o"></div>',
         'banana': '<div class="b a"></div>'
        }

d = {k: re.sub(r'class="([\w\- ]+)"', r'class="\1 ' + dict1[k] + '"', v) for k,v in dict2.items()}

print(d)
# {
#  'apple': '<div class="a hard tasty"></div>',
#  'orange': '<div class="o soft tasty"></div>',
#  'banana': '<div class="b a soft very-tasty"></div>'
#  }
```

Comment: I have accepted ajax's answer, I was not able to make this work on my datasets Laurent

Comment: It works on my side with your input data of your post. Can you tell me what fails on your side please ?

Comment: Sure, my dataset looks like below: `dict1 = {'btn-orange': 'p-3', 'btn-red': 'btn-transparent text-underline', 'quadruple': 'border border-primary'}` and 
`dict2 = {'btn-orange': '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" role="button">[]</a>', 'btn-red': '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button">[]</a>', 'quadruple': '<div class="col-lg-3">\n{}\n</div>'}`

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should have indicated your dataset in your question.

Comment: Works just like the accepted answer, thank you. I have multiple datasets that I was applying this to

Answer (score 0):

```
first = {
'apple': 'hard tasty', 'orange': 'soft tasty', 'banana': 'soft very-tasty'
}

second = {
'apple': '<div class="a"></div>',
'orange': '<div class="o"></div>',
'banana': '<div class="b a"></div>'
}

for k, v in second.items():
    lst = v.split("\"", 2)
    second[k] = "{} {}\"{}".format("\"".join(lst[:-1]), first[k], lst[-1])
```

**Output**

```
 {
 'apple': '<div class="a hard tasty"></div>',
 'orange': '<div class="o soft tasty"></div>',
 'banana': '<div class="b a soft very-tasty"></div>'
 }
```

Comment: This approach is great but it seems I may run into a problem if there's another tag with the `"class\="` tag in it, for example `'banana': '<div class="b a" role="button"></div>'` would become `<div class="b a soft very-tasty" role="button soft very-tasty"></div>`

Comment: i change it, but  it will work only if class is first attribute